# Execute the function every time that I change the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

I have made two different theme for my application, users can select them from the setting, I defined colors in the module and in the control, in a function, I defined color for every element in the screen. 
The problem is, I have to add this function to `viewdidload`, but when I go to setting and change the them, and come back to the page, the them will not changed, and I have to close the app in the simulator and open it again to see the changes, apparently `viewdidload` only execute once when the app will open, but it doesn't execute when the change the page. Is there anyway that I can use like `viewdidload` but it will execute every time that I enter the page? and It is not needed to close the app completely and open it again to see the changes. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: A better way to do this is to put a notification listener in each view controller that listens for a notification posted by the control that the user toggles to select a theme. When the user changes the theme, the control posts a notification, and every view controller listening for it simply updates its own view objects. This is a better way around your problem because I assume the user is allowed to change theme at any time regardless of how many view controllers (all over the app) may be open. All of the color changes would be instantaneous to the control, no need to close and reopen.

Comment: And as a nice touch you can animate the color change in the view controller where the control is so that the user sees an animating color shift whenever they toggle the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `viewWillAppear()` instead of `viewdidload` and it will be called every time that ViewController has appeared

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //Your changes 
 }
```